# accessing individual layers from a saved model

Tags: tensorflow, generative-models

I am in the process of writing a model where I have the layers of the model in the "def _*init*_(   )" section of a class

I want to save and load the model in the class' variables where i ahve stored the layers .

and inside this class are two models where model 1 is using the layers of model 2 to compute a loss function .

how will this system work if i were to **save the model ?**
(this is my first attempt at a custom model)

as far as I can tell the ways to save the model seems to restore the weights and biases in the moded in the variable that was holding it and i dont see how it will reflect in the class I have written .

https://youtu.be/dCKbRCUyop8?t=1061

trying to replicate something like what is said here int his video at 17:41

````
class mymodel(Model):
    def __init__(self,chandim=-1):
        #just an example
        super(mymodel, self).__init__()
        self.gdn1 = Dense(128 * 16 * 16, activation='relu')
        self.gbn1 = BatchNormalization(momentum=0.9)
        self.glr1 = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1)
        self.grs1 = Reshape((16, 16, 128))

        self.gcn2 = Conv2D(128, kernel_size=5, strides=1,padding='same')
        self.gbn2 = BatchNormalization(momentum=0.9)   
        #self.gdp2 = Dropout(0.5)
        self.glr2 = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1)
        
        self.gcn3 = Conv2DTranspose(128, 4, strides=2, padding='same')
        self.gbn3 = BatchNormalization(momentum=0.9)
        self.glr3 = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1)
    
    def get_model1(self,input_layer):
        hid = self.gdn1(input_layer)    
        hid = self.gbn1(hid)
        hid = self.glr1(hid)
        hid = self.grs1(hid)
        
        
        hid = self.gcn2(hid)    
        hid = self.gbn2(hid)
        hid = self.glr2(hid)
        out = Activation("tanh")(hid)
        

        model = Model(input_layer, out)
        model.summary()
        return model, out
    
    def get_model2(self,input_layer):
        hid = self.gcn3(input_layer)    
        hid = self.gbn3(hid)
        hid = self.glr3(hid)
        
        out = Activation("tanh")(hid)
        

        model = Model(input_layer, out)
        model.summary()
        return model
    
    def lossFn_model2(self,X,Y)
        bx0 = self.gdn1(X)    
        bx1 = self.gbn1(hid)
        bx2 = self.glr1(hid)
        bx3 = self.grs1(hid)

        #Note Shared Layers 

        by0 = self.gdn1(Y)    
        by1 = self.gbn1(hid)
        by2 = self.glr1(hid)
        by3 = self.grs1(hid)
        
        return tf.math.square(bx3-by3)
```
````

Comment: Could you please explain in simple 2-3 steps.  1. You want to load a model from disk. 2. Then copy a few of its layers to another model. Is this what you want to achieve

Comment: i want to save this model to disk
then load it at a later point in time
be able to share few of the layers in loaded model to another model. all this has to preferably happen through the class.
what you have suggested is close enough i could work with that too.